# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when saving HoloMap to GIF

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif, holoviews

I am trying to create an animated gig from a series of heat maps with HoloViews. 
I need to do this in a Python script, i. e. specifically not in a Jupyter notebook.

When saving the image, Python throws an error because it cannot create a temporary file in the temp-folder of the current user (this is under Windows). Happens regardless of the user, even when I run Python as admin.

When I stop in the debugger and change the temp-file path to some other place, e. g. Desktop, that works, but the resulting **holo.gif** in the working directory is empty (0 bytes). The temporary gif, though, is correctly animated, so I guess the code is basically OK.

[*Edit:* Not so sure anymore. I ran this the night through on 26.531 heat maps each of which consisted of a 5x5 grid. The process did not finish (i. e. did not hit the breakppoint at Image.py line 1966). Is there a way to do what I want that is less painfully slow?]

Answers to similar problems on StackOverflow did point to permission problems (but what kind of problem could that be if it doesn't even work for an admin?) and suggest saving to another location, which is impossible here as I have no control over where matplotlib will try to create temporary files.

The problem is specifically with gif's, I can create *.png or *.html output without error. (AFAIK, the difference is that gif-creation uses ImageMagick.)

Here's the code (construction of underlying heat map data left out):

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('matplotlib')

renderer = hv.renderer('matplotlib')
renderer.fps = 3

heatMapDict = {
    k: hv.HeatMap(measurements[k].sensors) for k in range(len(measurements))
}
holo = hv.HoloMap(heatMapDict, kdims='index')
renderer.save(holo, 'holo', fmt='gif')
```

And the traceback:

```
    INFO:matplotlib.animation:Animation.save using <class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cm3.py", line 69, in <module>
    renderer.save(holo, 'holo', fmt='gif')
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py", line 554, in save
    rendered = self_or_cls(plot, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\mpl\renderer.py", line 108, in __call__
    data = self._figure_data(plot, fmt, **({'dpi':self.dpi} if self.dpi else {}))
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\mpl\renderer.py", line 196, in _figure_data
    data = self._anim_data(anim, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\mpl\renderer.py", line 246, in _anim_data
    anim.save(f.name, writer=writer, **anim_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1174, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 232, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 583, in finish
    duration=int(1000 / self.fps))
  File "C:\Users\y2046\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1966, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\y2046\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4im5ozo8.gif'
```

*Addendum:*
I'm coming to think that this is not a permission problem after all. Perhaps it has to do with reentrancy and file-locking under Windows? The Python process in fact may create files in the temp directory, as proved by inserting the following test code before calling `renderer.save()`:

```
import os
import builtins
filename = 'C:\\Users\\y2046\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test.txt'
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
try:
    fp.write("first".encode('utf-8'))
finally:
    fp.close()
os.remove(filename)
```

I should test this under Linux. If it works there, there must be a bug in the Pillow writer.

Comment: Well what are the rights you have for this file?

Comment: @brainfuck4d as I said, happens even when I run this as admin with unrestricted rights. And when running under a user with restricted rights, the user can of course create arbitrary files in his own temp-directory. At least manually in Windows explorer. No idea why the Python process running under that same user appears to be unable to do the same.

Comment: Does this only occur with 26.531 or would 5 heatmaps be enough? Where is the limit? Is some windows energy saving mode or similar enabled?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest In fact 1 single heatmap is enough, which somehow counts against my hypotheses of file locking. Unless Image.py really goes ahead and tries to acquire a second lock on the file after creating it in order to manipulate the contents.

Comment: The same code works under CentOS 7. (Except I had to add `matplotlib.use('agg')`  to avoid use of tkinter which I did not find a simple way to install into Python 3.7.1) So now my current guess is that matplotlib gif animation has a Windows-specific bug.

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? I.e using a code one can copy and paste? Is this depending on the use of holoviews?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest here's an SSCE: https://gist.github.com/smillies/2575831ddfa5731b8d04d08d0f1bdad1    
I don't think it's holoviews, I think it's the interaction of my Windows system with matplotlib. But I do not have an example using only matplotlib.

Comment: That was more meant to trigger the removal of holoviews from the mwe.

Comment: Not being in any way familiar with this stuff, I fear that gist is as minimal as I can get.

Comment: The problem is when I create a minimal example that only uses matplotlib (see [here](https://gist.github.com/ImportanceOfBeingErnest/f44d5137fa44fa9f5e1833bb022d3eee)) it works as expected. I wouldn't preclude the holoviews [save function](http://holoviews.org/_modules/holoviews/plotting/renderer.html) to be responsible. But it would help if you could run the example i posted and see if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, I mean I do get the same error with the holoviews example you posted, but indeed the matplotlib-only example works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted my previous comment (not quite in time, unfortunately), because I made a silly mistake in testing and ran the wrong example. But I can in fact confirm that your MWE also works for me. So the problem with my example must be to do with holoviews after all, do you think?

Comment: It looks like it, although I currently cannot see where it comes from, because essentially holoviews does the same call to `FuncAnimation.save("fname", writer="pillow", fps=5)` at the end.

Comment: I played around a bit in the source code of holoviews and it also fails to save via `imagemagick` or `imagemagick_file`. So I'd say there is something broken with holoviews. (It might turn out that something should be changed inside of matplotlib, but only the holoview devs can tell us, what that would be.) So opening an issue with them might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something broken with HoloViews. I have opened [issue #3151](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/3151) with them.

Comment: Looks like a platform-specific difference in behavior for a Python system call. HoloViews master now has a workaround that will be in the latest release.